# How should I prepare as a baker, for Athens A protocol activation?

Tags: ledger, protocol, tezos-client, athens

Can someone provide a step-by-step guide to help bakers to be prepared for Athens A protocol activation? Do we need to upgrade Ledger baking software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed before and will probably be flagged. Nevertheless, the answer is: You only need to upgrade those commands that you are currently running with 003... to 004.... That's it. More info [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/what-steps-should-be-taken-to-safely-upgrade-a-baker-after-a-new-protocol-update?noredirect=1&lq=1).